# Get value between strings in RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net

I have a richtextbox filled with some text (e.g. [mplampla], [randomstring], [string]...).
The richtextbox has many lines.
I'm trying to get every value between "[" and "]" but I can't.

That's my code so far:

```
For Each line In RichTextBox1.Lines
        Dim string1 As String = line
        Dim finalstring As String = ""
        finalstring = string1.Split("[")(1).Split("]")(0)
        MsgBox(finalstring)
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get all the values inside the brackets by using a String.Split.

Regex is good at these things, but you can also just use the IndexOf function to find the brackets:

```
Dim words As New List(Of String)
Dim startIndex As Integer = 0
While startIndex > -1
  startIndex = rtb.Text.IndexOf("[", startIndex)
  If startIndex > -1 Then
    Dim endIndex As Integer = rtb.Text.IndexOf("]", startIndex)
    If endIndex > -1 Then
      words.Add(rtb.Text.Substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1))
    End If
    startIndex = endIndex
  End If
End While
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.ToArray))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
    For Each line In RichTextBox1.Lines
                Dim string1 As String = line
                Dim betastring As String = ""
                Dim finalstring As String = ""
                betastring = string1.Split("[")(1)
                finalstring = betastring .Split("]")(0)
                MsgBox(finalstring)
            Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty quickly with regular expressions using [positive lookarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups):

```
(?<=\[)(\w|\s)*(?=\])
```

Consider the following console app:

```vb
Dim str = "this is [my] string [with some] [brackets]"
Dim pattern = "(?<=\[)(\w|\s)*(?=\])"
Dim matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, pattern)

For Each match In matches
    Console.WriteLine(match)
Next
```

Which results in this output:

```
my
with some
brackets
```

Also, you could expand that to match multiline text by using the [`Regex.Matches(String, String, RegexOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b49yw9s8(v=vs.110).aspx) overload:

```vb
RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
```